# image files not showing up - using webpack file loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I have been trying to load images using webpack, but somehow it's not working.
here's the related code

```
 { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]' },
```

and here's one example of the component where the image should load

```
<ListItem
            leftAvatar={
              <Avatar src="assets/images-demo/avatars/128.jpg" />
            }
```

but when the page loads, I get

```
http://localhost:8080/assets/images-demo/avatars/128.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

In the network tab, I see the type of the images as text/html, (not sure why) and I see the initiator as DOMLazyTree. so, could you give me an idea of what's going wrong here?

Comment: did you try `import img from "path/to/image"` and use like `<Avatar src={img} />` ?

Comment: you mean import the image in file using the image?
but I already  did this -->               <Avatar src="assets/images-demo/avatars/128.jpg" />
and it will be a pain if I have to do this for all the images
or if I have to individually import all the images.

Comment: widthout importing your path is just  a string! https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#examples

Comment: ok. leyt me try that. in which file do I import the image? in the one where I used the url I mentioned above? or do you mean some other file? sorry, a little new to webpack and file loader

Comment: import in exact file which <Avatar /> is in.